# 'to be concerned to'

Tags: etymology, prepositions

> [ODO:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/concern) 1.4. be concerned ... **to** do something = Regard it as important to do something:
>
> [OED:](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/38153?rskey=VxdWfk&result=2&isAdvanced=false) III. Passive, ***to be concerned***.
>   This occurs in some senses which are non-existent or obsolete in the active; in other senses it is much more used than the active.
>
> †8. To be under the responsibility or obligation; to have it as one's business. *Obs.* (Cf. 4.)

'be concerned ... **to** do something' bothers me, but I can't pinpoint why. I guess that the problem is the preposition **to**.

Could someone please explain the significance of **to** here, and also the etymology of this phrasal verb?  I ask NOT about the above definitions which I already understand. I heed the Etymological Fallacy. 
I already read [this website](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2011/06/concerned.html) but it doesn't dig deeper than the definition.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, one can see some real examples with

["**be concerned to do something**"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22be%20concerned%22%20...%20%22to%20do%20something%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22be%20concerned%20to%20do%20something%22) 8 results

at Google Books.

E.g.

> Planning Investment in Bolivia: The Changing Role of the ... - Page 17
>   George Irvin - 1979
>
> Government now seems **to be concerned to do something** to redress
>   this imbalance, emphasis being given to increasing cultivated areas of
>   staple crops (particularly wheat and maize) as well as improving
>   extension, marketing and

In this context, IMO:

to be **concerned** to do something = to be **/preoccupied/interested/** about doing something

As to "to," it's naturally there, as in

to want to do something.

Furthermore, you seem to have the idea that:

*I am **/preoccupied about/interested in/** doing something.*

are passive constructs. They are not. They **describe a state of mind**. Would you say that:

*I am hot/cold.*

are passive? I hope not.

This is a related passive construct:

> Portraits in Science Ann Mozley Moyal - 1994
>
> I enjoyed my schooling, and after primary school went to Unley High
>   School, where I was fortunate in having **teachers who really made me
>   interested** in what I was doing.

An agent ("teachers") is clearly in evidence, as well as an action - not a state. Thus passive.

Now, let's look at the equivalence/translation showed here:

> [Recycling Advanced English with Removable Key](https://books.google.ca/books?id=rd1rtazF7UYC&pg=PA233&dq=%22be%20interested%20to%20do%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Xa4eVfWqBrDPsQS8z4GQDw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22be%20interested%20to%20do%22&f=false) - Page 233 Clare West -
>   2010
>
> be interested to do: would like to
>
> ***I'm interested to know*** what you thought of the film.

Well, if "I'm interested"  can be followed by an infinitive, so can "I'm concerned.":-)

Thus, based on the latest reference:

*Government now seems **to be concerned to do something** to redress this imbalance.*

can be expressed/translated as:

*It seems that the government **would like to do something** to redress this imbalance.*

This, to me, is much more understandable to anyone.

Not only that, but **I hope that a "to" after "would like" doesn't raise any question marks**:-)

Comment: Sorry if I've erred, but could you please clarify how this answers my question? Your answer appears only to restate the definition, which I already understand, and to exemplify with sentences.

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal Well, you said it bothers you, so I showed you real examples from educated people, to show to you it's OK and you have to accept it. Further, this is not a phrasal verb. Further, I made the comparison with "want to do something." Do you have an objection with "to" there? Further, I presented to you other possible "translations." IMO, this should answer your question, at least in part.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, I want to understand more than simply `accept[ing] it`. What grammatical structure is this, so that I can replace `phrasal verb` ? I don't object to `to` in "want to do something.", but this differs because here `want` is an infinitive. `to be concerned` is passive. Alas, the 'translations' don't help; they just repeat the definition.

Comment: @Law There's no passive voice there. Check the updated answer.